# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pointerIndex 0 for MotionEvent

Tags: android, android-gesture

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
  if (event == null) {
     return false;
  }else{
    try {
        scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(event));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
  }
 ...
 return false;
})
```

`scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(event))` causese the following exception **occasionally**:

```
Class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 Stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid pointerIndex 0 for MotionEvent { action=MOVE, pointerCount=0, historySize=4, eventTime=603786531923251, downTime=603786191066000, deviceId=5, source=TOUCHSCREEN, displayId=0, eventId=-1007465244}
        at android.view.MotionEvent.nativeGetRawAxisValue(MotionEvent.java)
        at android.view.MotionEvent.getRawX(MotionEvent.java:3196)
        at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:598)
        at android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ScaleGestureDetector.java:275)
```

Relevant code:

```
   scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getActivity(), new ScaleListener());

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            try {
              ...

            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Again, `scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(event))` throws the exception only **occasionally**. Could anyone shed some light on this?